# Powershell cannot use database view unless recompiled

Tags: oracle, powershell, view, compilation

Powershell program on Widnows server 2012 performs some database operations in Oracle database using regular Oracle client. Database is XE 11g.
Program first retrieves data from a view and then loops through recordset and sends processed data to SQL server using its client.
The problem is it sees source recordset as empty. View is just fine, without problems. But after (special) recompilation powershell suddenly sees the data.

When PS is executed for the first time, it sees no data.
When view is recompiled in SQL developers, still nothing.
When view is recompield in Toad, then PS sees the data. Bingo.
I have tried compilation sql inside PS program before data retrieval, no luck. Compilation works ok but without expected results.
I have also tried in PS to connect, alter/compile, close connection and reconnect to continue processing, no luck.

This situation seems very wierd. I don't understand why PS program can't see any data and after "special" compilation only inside Toad it can see the data.
After the program is closed and opened and started again, it's the same, no data visible.

Has anyone else been in the twilight zone?

Comment: Possibly with the view text there might be a clue. If you can see the data in SQLplus but not powershell, the problem is probably in the powershell bit. If you can't see data in sqlplus, you can eliminate that.

Comment: Maybe a caching problem? Does the PS script work with a simple select like `SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Day, ddth Month, yyyy')"Today" FROM dual;`? If it doesn't, the script has got issues, if it does, the view might be the likely culprit.

Comment: @GaryMyers, I can see the data in view without problem. On both clients, SQL dev. and Toad, it works as expected. I executed it right now, just in case.

Comment: @vonPryz, here is that query: SELECT * FROM v_output WHERE proc_det IS NULL AND exp_erp = 1. I just tried to execute without first where clause and I got records. Interesting. (since all records were processed, with both clauses I get empty recordset, so it's applicable on next processing)
As you suggested, I will try other options to get some data.

Comment: I have news. Although I was 100% sure, I was wrong.
I did not have commit at the end of procedure that filled the data.
Therefore change was not visible to other sessions.
And, whatever Toad does to "only recompile view", it has performed commit during that process.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing commit at the end of procedure that filled data which should appear in the view.
Case closed.